# Compilation error on this string

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create the following string:

```
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Parent.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "test", "<script type='text/javascript' langauage='javascript' src='test.js'></script>");
    }
</script>
```

yet i get a compilation error in VS saying "Newline in constant"

Comment: Should be fine. Are you sure it's that line that's the problem? Can you put it in context?

Comment: That string is fine in my tests. Why not use the ClientScriptManager to add the script include. Its much neater solution

Comment: I have updated my question with greater context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the end script tag

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827420

Solve it wit:

```
".....<"+"/SCRIPT>"
```

or maybe

```
".....<\/script>"
```

Use ClientScriptManager instead and use RegisterClientScriptInclude. This way you only need to have the file name in a string.

[ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2552td66.aspx)

```
ClientScriptManager scriptManager = new ClientScriptManager(); scriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude("filename.js");
```

Comment: I like your alternative solution by using RegisterClientScriptInclude. =)

Answer (score 2):

```
"<script type='text/javascript' langauage='javascript' src='test.js'></script>"
```

Well yeah, you've got string containing </script> inside a <script> element. That closes the outer <script>, so the code that appears to be inside your runat-server script is just:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Parent.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "test", "<script type='text/javascript' langauage='javascript' src='test.js'>
```

And as the error says, that contains a "string with no terminating double-quote.

Try escaping the characters so the other script block doesn't see them as markup:

```
"\x3Cscript type='text/javascript' src='test.js'>\x3C/script>"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@"<script language="Javascript" src="/utility/thickbox/thickbox-custom.js"></script>"
```